# Problems mapping 2 lists with different names using Java modelMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have 4 classes;

```
public class Class1
{
    private String id;
    private List<Class1a> class1aItems = null;

    ....
}

public class Class1a
{
    private String id;
    private String info;

    ....
}


public class Class2
{
    private String id;
    private List<Class2a> class2aItems = null;

    ...
}

public class Class2a
{
    private String id;
    private String info;

    ...
}
```

and **i can't set the same name** to the lists in Class1 and Class2.

Then, i have to map Class1 into Class2 using automapper like this:

```
TypeMap<Class1, Class2> typeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(Class1.class, Class2.class);
        typeMap.addMapping(Class1::getClass1aItems, Class2::setClass2aItems);

        Class2 class2 = modelMapper.map(class1, Class2.class);
```

For the main classes it works (Class1 is mapped into Class2) except for the list. Class2 have an empty class2aItems while before the mapping class1aItems was populated with 3 items.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try implement `java.io.Serializable` in your destiny Class

```
public class Class2 implements Serializable
{
    private String id;
    private List<Class2a> class2aItems = null;

    ...
}

public class Class2a implements Serializable
{
    private String id;
    private String info;

    ...
}
```